# Use transformation of an equation within a Matlab function?

Tags: matlab, function, optimization, anonymous-function, mle

I am trying to code a very basic Mean Likelihood Estimator function that relies on the Optimization Toolbox's `fminsearch()` function. I try to pass a function handle as an input and optimize the sum of the neg. of the function's log. My code is:

```
function [ params, max ] = routine( fun )
%UNTITLED3 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

[filename,path] = uigetfile('*.'); #To grab the csv file location
name = strcat(path,filename);
data = csvread(name);

lh = @(x) sum(-log( fun(x) )); <-------- ERROR LINE

options = optimset('Display', 'off', 'MaxIter', 100000, 'TolX', 10^-20, 'TolFun', 10^-20);
[theta, max1] = fminsearch(lh, [0,1], options);

params = theta
max = max1

end
```

The line in the middle is giving me this error:

```
Undefined function or variable 'data'.

Error in @(x)(1/(sqrt(2*pi)*x(2)))*exp((-(data-x(1)).^2)/(2*x(2)^2))

Error in @(x)sum(-log(fun(x)),data)

Error in fminsearch (line 200)
fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});
```

Now, outside this code, this works perfectly fine, infuriatingly enough.

```
pan = @(x)sum(-log((1/(sqrt(2*pi)*x(2)))*exp((-(data-x(1)).^2)/(2*x(2)^2))));
options = optimset('Display', 'off', 'MaxIter', 100000, 'TolX', 10^-20, 'TolFun', 10^-20);
[theta, max1] = fminsearch(pan, [0,1], options);
```

For some reason, transforming the equation the way I do in the middle makes the `data` var. invisible. How should I correctly apply the transformation to my equation such that this code works?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html#f4-71621) on anonymous functions. Here's the relevant part

> ### Variables in the Expression
>
> Function handles can store not only an expression, but also variables that the expression requires for evaluation.
>
> For example, create a function handle to an anonymous function that
>   requires coefficients `a`, `b`, and `c`.
>
> ```
> a = 1.3;
> b = .2;
> c = 30;
> parabola = @(x) a*x.^2 + b*x + c;
> ```
>
> Because `a`, `b`, and `c` are available at the time you create `parabola`, **the function
>   handle includes those values. The values persist within the function
>   handle** even if you clear the variables:
>
> ```
> clear a b c
> x = 1;
> y = parabola(x)
> ```
>
> y = 31.5000
>
> **To supply different values for the coefficients, you must create a new function handle**

In your case the value of `data` that you read in won't be available to `fun` since the function handle was defined before `data`. Instead we can just make `data` a parameter of `fun` then we avoid the problem all together.

---

*calling code*

```
myfun = @(x,data) (1/(sqrt(2*pi)*x(2)))*exp((-(data-x(1)).^2)/(2*x(2)^2));
[params,max] = routine(myfun);
```

---

*routine.m* (the bit which needs to be changed)

```
function [ params, max ] = routine( fun )
...
lh = @(x) sum(-log( fun(x,data) ));
...
end
```